# Stop the gitlab pipeline if previous stages failed

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab pipeline which consiste of multiple stages[checkout->build->test->Deploy->cleanup->validation->terminate ec2].I have 3 requirement.

1. if any stage before the deploy stage failed, the pipeline stopped immediately.
2. if the deploy stage succeeds then the cleanup stage must skip and continue with another stage.
3. when only the deploy stage failed then only and must clean up stage run and exit the pipeline.

Here is my example pipeline.

```
stages: 
  - checkout
  - build
  - test
  - Deploy
  - cleanup
  - reset
  - Jenkins Jobs
  - validation


checkout:
    stage: checkout
    tags:
        - publishing
    script:
        - echo checkout

build:
    stage: build
    tags:
      - automated-content-publishing
    script:
      -  echo build

test:
    stage: test
    tags:
      - publishing
    script:
      - echo test

Deploy:
  stage: Deploy
  tags:
      - publishing
  script:
      - echo deploy
    

Cleanup:
  stage: Cleanup
  tags:
    - publishing
  script:
    - echo clean-up
  when: on_failure

reset:
    stage: Nexus Insert
    tags:
      - publishing
    script:
      - echo reset
      

Jenksin Jobs:
  stage: Jenkins Jobs
  tags:
    - publishing
  script:
      - echo jenkins jobs

      

vilidation:
  stage: Vilidation
  tags:
    - publishing
  script:
    - echo validation
```

this pipeline works perfectly in 2 and 3 requirements. pipeline not working for 1 requirement.  if any stage failed before the deploy stage failed cleanup stage call.

I want to call the cleanup stage only and only when the deploy stage failed.

Please guide me to build this case.

Comment: If your cleanup stage job only specific to the deploy job, why can't you just do these stuff in the deploy job ```after_script``` section?

Comment: Agree, but in my case cleanup stage has multiple jobs, and as per the document we can only execute the command in after_script.

Comment: Do you look at `needs`?  You could add dependency to your jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this

```
Deploy:
  stage: Deploy
tags:
  - publishing
script:
  - echo deploy

...

Cleanup:
  stage: Cleanup
  tags:
    - publishing
  script:
    - echo clean-up
  needs: 
    - job: Deploy
  when: on_failure
```

If **deploy** stage has many jobs just add them to `needs` section. For more info look at [reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needs).